# C# opening website with authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, system.diagnostics

i need to help about using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(..) function with authentication .

I am using following code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://" + textBox_Old_IP.Text + ":" + combobox_ssh.SelectedItem + "/authorize?UserName=ROOT&Password=123456&submit=")
```

However, It doesn't work everytime.I mean that it logins succesfully sometimes, but another time it fails and browser gives "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" . Is there another way to open website with authentication? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work every time? How are we to know what `doesn't work` means? It doesn't run the process? It doesn't log you in? It doesn't compile? What?

Comment: sorry for  ambiguous statement. I mean that it logins succesfully sometimes, but another time it fails  and browser gives "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Comment: Seems like it's a problem on the server's end

Comment: if it's something on the other end, you could consider transient error handling, like that which is provided by https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not consider using WebClient or HttpRequest?

Comment: It can be easier and far more stable or managable using WebClient.UploadValues(String, NameValueCollection) to realize your requirement